# Show changes in php variables without reloading the page

Tags: php, ajax

```
$getchat = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Chat ORDER BY Date DESC");
$getchat->execute();
$getchat1 = $getchat->get_result();
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($getchat1)){
    $chatdisplay .= "<div style='border: 2px solid hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
-webkit-animation: rainbow 5s infinite alternate;border-left: 0px; border-
right: 0px;'><p style='margin-left: 3%'>{$row2['Steamname']}</p><img 
style='margin-left: 5%; border: solid 2px black' src='{$row2['Avatar']}'><p 
style='color: black; margin-left: 5%;'>{$row2['Text']}</p></div> ";
}
$getchat->close();


<div>
<?php echo $chatdisplay ?>
</div>
```

Need help with showing changes in $chatdisplay without having to reload the page. I've tried ajax.load but it hasn't shown any changes in $chatdisplay.

Comment: Show your javascript. You need to replace the existing HTML with what you receive from the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a basic chat application you need to do like this 
[image]

1. you need to make api call to the server for getting the new messages normally it will be a continues call with 1 second or 2 second delay for that we can use "setTimeout()",
2. getting the response from server you can use the similar code you mentioned above but you need add one more field in table status for status read -1 and status not read -0  by default you can set it 0. after making select query you need to execute update query to update the status to 1
   so you all the time you will get unread messages
3. the response from the server you can append to the chatbox

-I did a simple search in google found some samples [sample](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931), [google search](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=L0hnWs79I4HSUdKnhbgC&q=php%20ajax%20simple%20chat&oq=php%20ajax%20simple%20chat&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1l9.1337.5761.0.5855.21.15.0.0.0.0.651.2788.3-3j1j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..15.6.2785.0..35i39k1j0i131i67k1j0i67k1.0.SIf7rn1hTF4)